# Base64 encoding of a SHA256 hash

Tags: hash, sha256, jwt

I'm currently reading up on JWTs and have written something to create them. When I created my JWT I noticed that my signature was not being encoded properly.

For instance, given the hash

```
9B2317C2C941A179130D0D28961AB542C88745658BE328F557422EA0AF8F60E8
```

My code produces

```
OUIyMzE3QzJDOTQxQTE3OTEzMEQwRDI4OTYxQUI1NDJDODg3NDU2NThCRTMyOEY1NTc0MjJFQTBBRjhGNjBFOA==
```

What I'm expecting to get is

```
myMXwslBoXkTDQ0olhq1QsiHRWWL4yj1V0IuoK+PYOg=
```

Why are encoded hashes so different and what am I missing?

Comment: What you think is the hash is not, in fact, the hash.  It is a hex-encoded string representing the hash value.  You need to un-encode it to the byte-sequence that is in fact the hash before base64 encoding.  Currently you're just base64 encoding the string.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I also found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278170/md5-hash-and-base64-encoding which helped me to understand what was going on.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are doing a conversion from hex encoding (or base16 if you like) to base64. So you are base64 encoding the ASCII characters `9` (57), `B` (66) and `2` (50) giving you `OUIy`.

What you should be doing is base64 encoding *the raw bytes*. So you should encode `0x9B` (155) and `0x23` (35) giving you `myM`.

Answer (score 15):

This should do;

```
echo 9B2317C2C941A179130D0D28961AB542C88745658BE328F557422EA0AF8F60E8 | xxd -r -p | base64
```

Output:

```
myMXwslBoXkTDQ0olhq1QsiHRWWL4yj1V0IuoK+PYOg=
```